# openshift writing templates create route on condition

Tags: templates, conditional-statements, openshift

I wrote a template for Openshift online, but I cannot find a way to declare an object ("kind": "Route")  conditioned (i.e. only:parameter=value). My target is to deploy two services one bound to a route, the other not, using the same template.
Thanks for any suggestion.
Lorenzo

Comment: OpenShift templates do not support conditions. But you can create 2 services in the same template and only expose one of them. Perhaps if you provided some of the code, or further explanation, we could help.

Comment: Thanks Will (sorry for late reply). I've choosen to create a clone template of the first, removing the routing part.